# Multiplayer Rock-Paper-Scissors

Tags: code-golf

## Objective

Given a nonempty multiset of `Rock`, `Paper`, and `Scissors`, output the winning figure according to the special rule.

## Background

For a multiplayer RPS, if all three figures come out, usually it's considered a draw. But by that rule, the probability to draw would dramatically increase when there are many and many players.

Let's resolve that by a special rule.

## Input

Though defined as a multiset, the input type and format doesn't matter. Valid formats of the input include:

- A multiset
- A sequential container with or without guarantee of order
- An size-3 array of integers representing the count of each of RPS

Also, `Rock`, `Paper`, and `Scissors` may be encoded by an arbitrary type.

## The Special Rule and Output

Let's say \$r\$ `Rock`s, \$p\$ `Paper`s, and \$s\$ `Scissors`-es(?) are given.

- If one of them is zero, output the winning figure of the other two.
- If none of them is zero, allot them a score by multiplicating the number of themselves and the number of the figure they win to. That is, `Rock` gets score \$r×s\$, `Paper` gets score \$p×r\$, and `Scissors` get score \$s×p\$.

  - If the scores don't tie, output the figure with the maximum score.
  - If the scores tie by two figures, output the winning figure amongst the two figures.
  - Otherwise, output a fourth value indicating draw.
- Otherwise, output either the only figure or the fourth value.

The output type and format doesn't matter.

## Rule about code golf

Invalid inputs (Empty container, contains a fourth value, etc) fall into *don't care* situation.

## Example

Given the following input:

```
[Rock, Rock, Rock, Paper, Paper, Scissors, Scissors]
```

`Rock` gets score 3×2=6, `Paper` gets score 2×3=6, and `Scissors` get score 2×2=4. Since `Paper` wins to `Rock`, the output is `Paper`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "The output format must match the input's format." Say, can the output be one of the numbers 0,1,2,3 for rock, paper, scissors, tie?

Comment: Is the "If one of them is zero, ..." rule necessary? That side would always get a score of 0 anyway.

Comment: I'd really suggest allowing input to just be the counts of the three symbols. Getting those counts from a list of items seems like an extraneous step that all solutions will do. (Edit: On second thought, I'm less sure about this. Maybe some solutions would get the product of counts directly by counting pairs via two loops.)

Comment: @Monicareinstate, I'm just making the rule intuitively understandable. Nice inspection for a code golf tho.

Comment: What's a multiset?

Comment: @S.S.Anne An associative container with entries repeatable.

Comment: Not really golfed, but the homepage of https://haxe.org/ contains a cool Rock-Paper-Scissors example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>14</s> 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ćü*ZÊ2βD3*7%M
```

Input as a list of integers in the order \$[r,s,p]\$.
Output as one of the following four:

```
Rock wins:      3
Scissors wins:  5
Paper wins:     6
Tie:            0
```

-1 byte thanks to *@xnor*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SNvhPVpRh7uMzm1yMdYyV/X9/z/aWMdIxygWAA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##AVkApv9vc2FiaWX/MsOdM8Ojdnk/IiDihpIgIj95/8SGw7wqWsOKMs6yRDMqNyVN/0Q/IlRpZSAgIFJvY2sgIFNjaXNzb3JzIFBhcGVyIiNzw6giICjDvykiLClc/w).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ć              # Enclose the (implicit) input-list, appending its own head
               #  i.e. input=[3,2,2] → STACK: [[3,2,2,3]
 ü             # For each overlapping pair: [a,b,c,d] → [[a,b],[b,c],[c,d]]
  *            #  Multiply them together
               #   STACK: [[6,4,6]]
   Z           # Get the maximum (without popping)
               #   STACK: [[6,4,6],6]
    Ê          # Check which of the values in the list are NOT equals to this maximum
               #  STACK: [[0,1,0]]
     2β        # Convert this list of 0s and 1s from a binary list to integer
               #  STACK: [2]
       D       # Duplicate it
               #  STACK: [2,2]
        3*     # Multiply it by 3
               #  STACK: [2,6]
          7%   # Take modulo-7:
               #  STACK: [2,6]
            M  # Push the largest value on the stack
               #  STACK: [2,6,6]
               # (after which the top of the stack is output implicitly as result)
```

After the `Ćü*ZÊ` we can have the following values:

```
                One of:
Rock wins:      [[0,1,1], [0,0,1]]
Scissors wins:  [[1,0,1], [1,0,0]]
Paper wins:     [[1,1,0], [0,1,0]]
Ties:           [[0,0,0]]
```

Converting those from binary-lists to integers:

```
                One of:
Rock wins:      [3, 1]
Scissors wins:  [5, 4]
Paper wins:     [6, 2]
Ties:           [0]
```

The `3*7%` (thanks to *@xnor*!) will map the lower values to the higher values in the pair, and will also unsure the lower values won't increase.

> This works because the pairs `[1,3], [2,6], [4,5]` are constructed from bits where the second number has two bits set: that of the first number, and the bit position to its right, wrapping around in 3 bits. This comes from the binary-list of the RPS game. We can do the set-next-bit with `*3` and enforce 3-bit wrapping with `%7`.

```
                One of:
Rock wins:      [3→2, 1→3]
Scissors wins:  [5→1, 4→5]
Paper wins:     [6→4, 2→6]
Ties:           [0]
```

After which we can use `M` to only keep the largest value on the stack for our result:

```
                One of:
Rock wins:      [3, 3]
Scissors wins:  [5, 5]
Paper wins:     [6, 6]
Ties:           [0]
```

Comment: It might be useful that in each of the pairs in the mapping, the second number is the first one times 5 modulo 7.

Comment: @xnor Hmm, but how to effectively combine it so it won't map the other value. I could use `D5*7%‚ß` (Duplicate; use your `*5%7`; pair these two integers together; and pop and push the smallest integer), but unfortunately it's also 14 bytes: [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##AVkApv9vc2FiaWX/MsOdM8Ojdnk/IiDihpIgIj95/8SGw7wqWsOKMs6yRDUqNyXigJrDn/9EPyJUaWUgUm9jayBQYXBlciAgU2Npc3NvcnMiI3PDqCIgKMO/KSIs/w). PS: If we could somehow map the `[1,4,2]` to `[3,5,6]` and ensure that same fomula won't make `[3,5,6]` themselves larger, I could do it with `D...M` instead of `D...‚ß` to save a byte.

Comment: It looks like the reverse map of `*3%7` would meet your criterion.

Comment: @xnor Awesome, thanks! :) Btw, I've asked Arnauld a similar question once before, but do you have some kind of test script to get certain magic formulas for the integers, or do you create that from scratch every time depending on the challenge and required mapping? Could you give me some tips on how to make it myself? PS: I could have easily written a test script in the form of `*a%b`, but I thought it would have required more operations.. How do you know how many operations (and which) are sufficient in terms of multiply, modulo, bitwise operations, etc.?

Comment: I've used a script for some brute-forcing before, and I'm rewriting it into a form that's less hacked-together that I intend to share. In this case though, I didn't use anything like that here, or even coded anything, but thought up the formula logically. The pairs`(1,3), (2,6), (4,5)` are constructed from bits where the second number has two bits set: that of the first number, and the bit position to its right, wrapping around in 3 bits. This comes from the RPS game. We can do the set-next-bit with `*3` and enforce 3-bit wrapping with `%7`.

Comment: About your point about the formula being surprisingly short, it might be, probably because it comes "by design" rather than working by coincidental overfitting. I only have a vague sense of how long to expect a formula to need, and luck plays a big role, but at times I've estimated the number of possible formulas and the chance that a random mapping works.

Comment: Thinking through some bit logic, `~(n*2%7)&n` converts `[3,5,6]` to `[1,4,2]` while leaving the latter unchaged.

Comment: Actually, `n*5%7&n` can fix the `*5%7` version to not affect the powers of 2.

Comment: @xnor Ah, now the `*3%7` makes a lot more sense when looking at the binary-lists (basically the bits of the integers) that I had before the base conversion. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: And I look forward seeing your test script one day when you're posting it. I might try to make some test scripts myself for various operations, especially for 1-byte operations in 05AB1E, which also includes things like `2**n`, `10**n`, `floor`, `ceil`, `round`, `gcd`, first/last digit, `abs(a-b)`, etc. etc. Although I'll start with the basics. ;) I probably also won't do it in 05AB1E, since it's performance isn't the best tbh. So I'll probably try some things in Java when I have the time.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
lambda r,s,p:[s>p<=r>0,p>r<=s>0,r>s<=p>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYwxDsIwEAT7vGLLWHIRQWfl/Ii0kMJADJbAOd2ZgtcbHAHSFjvS7PKr3Na8q5GO9R4ep0uAWLXsDup5JPGDZS8j6aeI15HYD3OdQJCQr0u/N10XV4EgZUyuQwP9wUb8J6SIfrs3IEI/WLQYd15zSfm5NIcl5dI0qAUbi/id1Dc)

Takes counts as `(r,s,p)`. Outputs a three-element list with `True` at the position of the winner, or all `False`'s if there's a tie or only a single figure appearing.

```python
Rock:     [True, False, False]
Scissors: [False, True, False]
Paper:    [False, False, True]
Tie:      [False, False, False]
```

We use an alternate characterization without multiplication (except when only one figure is present). Below is the condition for Rock winning, with Scissors and Paper having similar conditions.

> Rock wins if: Paper has the fewest, strictly fewer than Scissors but possibly the same as Rock.

We can write this in Python as `s>p<=r` using inequality chaining.

Unfortunately, this doesn't correctly handle the special case when `r=p=0`, saying that Rock wins even though only Scissors is present. To fix this, we strengthen the condition for Rock to win to include `r>0` via `s>p<=r>0`, which makes the only-Scissors case give all `False` for every condition, matching a tie.

---

**44 bytes**

```python
lambda r,s,p:r*s==s*p==p*r or[s>p<=r,p>r<=s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc2xDsIwEAPQvV/hsYkyINiiXj@iK2UI0EAkSE53ZeDrg1IBkpcn2TK/13vJ@xppro/wPF8DxKljL1aJ1DIRW0GRo448kDgeZSA91QkECfm29AfTdbEIBClj8h0a9IdN/BdSRL89GBCh3zm0GH8peU35tbQOS8prq0Ed2DjE76R@AA)

Takes counts as `(r,s,p)`. Outputs as:

```python
Rock:     [True, False]
Scissors: [False, True]
Paper:    [False, False]
Tie:      True
```

The "Tie" case also includes where there's only a single figure present.

Comment: By my reading of the question, for an input of `[Scissors, Scissors]` you are allowed to output either `Scissors wins` or `Tie`, which would save 6 bytes.

Comment: @Neil Do you mean by getting rid of the `>0`'s? The issue with that is for inputs `[0, 2, 0]` for two Scissors, the code would actually gives that Rock wins. The difficulty is that in a similarly ordered input like `[1, 2, 1]`, we should in fact say that Rock wins due to it winning tiebreak between Rock and Scissors. So the two-zeros case is special.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @Noodle9 Yup, good catch, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>61</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>53</s></sup> 52 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)!!!
Saved 3 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

Uses [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)'s [formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202941/9481) converted to \$3\$ for Rock, \$2\$ for Scissors, \$1\$ for Paper, and \$0\$ for a tie or only a single figure appearing.

```c
f(r,s,p){r=s>p&p<=r&&r?3:p>r&r<=s&&s?2:r>s&s<=p&&p;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZFBbsIwEEX3OcVvJKy4BInCjsThCK3aLruJjANWizOaCXSBOHvqhEIWljzvydb8GbvYW9v3Tca55KQvbKQiRaVhpXi73lDFiksjSsl2teFKlJSGlKLi2ttDzc@wbTg77jIfOgSNSwL59Z09ILtVsLU4rDdg1504IH1v7Xda3MVqEh/Wi7Qsk3yZ5FtNjieznMyndyPfuaY@/XSTeG1JngZ1Ta7JsfYh05dkaPMIg3WRNC1jbJvNsuDyWMznrBM8sEQsI5aIJ06R08jplhC@QcaYQ@IhGIOljmPpfDi5oTMQx3dNls52GNLjLIjXe97/ckyIRYWZfIU0B@eQHJQ/JnxfktbDpzFU/wc)

Comment: The first `&&` in each part can be `&` for -3 (i.e. `(s>p&&p<=r&&r)` to `(s>p&p<=r&&r)`).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Interesting - thanks! :-)

Comment: `&&p?1:0` ~> `&!!p`?

Comment: @Arnauld Very sweet - thanks! :-)

Comment: @ceilingcat Very good, now realise the `?1:0` was totally redundant - thanks! :-)